# Python Tkinter: App hangs when changing window title via callback event

Tags: python, callback, tkinter, python-2.7

I'm creating a simple Python UI via Tkinter, and I'd like use `self.title` to have the window title change when a callback event is generated.

If I bind the event to a button, or call the event handler directly within the Tk thread, the window title changes as expected. However, I intend this event to be invoked by a separate thread, and I've found that using `title` in the callback event handler causes the app to hang.

Other tasks that I have in the event handler (such as updating a label) work just fine, so I have to assume that the event is being invoked properly. I've tried `wm_title` instead of `title`, but didn't see a difference. I've dug around and found nothing odd about `title`'s usage, just call it with a string to set the title.

Here's a stripped-down sample that replicates the problem (I'm running v2.7.1 on WinXP FYI); the app runs fine for 10 seconds (can move the window, resize, etc.), after which `Timer` generates the event and the app then freezes.

```
import Tkinter
import threading

class Gui(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.title('Original Title')
        self.label = Tkinter.Label(self, text='Just a Label.',
            width=30, anchor='center')
        self.label.grid()

        self.bind('<<change_title>>', self.change_title)

        timer = threading.Timer(10, self.event_generate, ['<<change_title>>'])
        timer.start()

    def change_title(self, event=None):
        self.title('New Title')

G = Gui(None)
G.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter is not thread safe. You're probably bumping up against the unpredictability of using multiple threads with a library that isn't thread safe. Btw: are you aware that tkinter has a function ('after') which you can use instead of a timer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered the same problem, where the UI hangs when calling self.title() from a thread other than the main thread. Tkinter expects all UI stuff to be done in the same thread (the main thread).

My solution was to have the separate thread put functions in a queue. The queue is serviced periodically by the main thread, making use of the after(ms) function provided by Tkinter. Here's an example with your code:

```
import Tkinter
import threading
from Queue import Queue, Empty

class Gui(Tkinter.Tk):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui_queue = Queue()
        self._handle_ui_request()
        self.title('Original Title')
        self.label = Tkinter.Label(self, text='Just a Label.',
            width=30, anchor='center')
        self.label.grid()

        self.bind('<<change_title>>', self.change_title)

        timer = threading.Timer(1, self.event_generate, ['<<change_title>>'])
        timer.start()

    def change_title(self, event=None):
        # Separate the function name, it's args and keyword args, 
        # and put it in the queue as a tuple.
        ui_function = (self.title, ('New Title',), {})
        self.ui_queue.put(ui_function)

    def _handle_ui_request(self):
        '''
        Periodically services the UI queue to handles UI requests in the main thread.
        '''
        try:
            while True:
                f, a, k = self.ui_queue.get_nowait()
                f(*a, **k)
        except Empty:
            pass

        self.after(200, self._handle_ui_request)


G = Gui(None)
G.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your code actually runs fine to me.

Except that, when interrupted before the ten secs, it says "RuntimeError: main thread is not in main loop"

I'm using python 2.6.6 under ubuntu 10.10

Hope this was of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it as well with 2.6.2 (Windows) and the caption/title didn't change.  No runtime error though.